# How to break headers with `sideways` into more than one line?

Tags: tables, rotating

I have following table:

```
\begin{table}[ht]\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|lp{1cm}p{1cm}}
\hline
   \begin{sideways}Parameter\end{sideways} & 
   \begin{sideways}Long header name ... \end{sideways} & 
   \begin{sideways}Long header..\end{sideways} \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}

\caption{Summary}
\label{tab:summary}
\end{table}
```

How to break side-wayed headers, so the can take two lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [minipage](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.html#minipage) environment or a [`\parbox`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.html#g_t_005cparbox) of a certain width.

```
\begin{sideways}\parbox{4cm}{Long header name ...}\end{sideways}
```